# Compositing nodes, toon effect and glow

Tags: compositing-nodes, emission

I am using the showed nodes to add a border effect to the final composition, the effect is fine everywhere but on the glow for the emission materials, on them, I see a dark border around the material which I want to get rid of it, how can I do that?

[image: composite nodes]

Done with freestyle

[image: freestyle output]

New update: as I understand, when I activate "Bloom" on View layer properties, it gives me an input on the compositing which is only the glow, I tried to "put it above" the rest of the composition with the color mix node and it gives me the following image, as you see, instead on that, now is giving me a weird black door, what am I doing wrong?
[image: composite with separated glow]

Comment: @ChristopherBennett the bottom part is just for testing purposes, as you see, at the bottom I don't have neither the border lines nor the border on the glow, what I want is to keep the border lines without keeping the lines on the glow part

Comment: On second thought, it looks like the RGB to BW is making the glow from the light pure white, then the invert is making it black, then you're multiplying the (now black) glow over the regular image

Comment: @ChristopherBennett about your second comment I tried without RBG to BW and / or invent, with this changes tuhe border just changes the color to white or to any color, about your third comment, how can I use the freestyle? could you please provide me a guide?

Comment: Under the _Render Properties_ tab, down near the bottom there is a checkbox that says "Freestyle". Check the box and render the image - the border only appears in the render. There are a number of settings you can change underneath, and a whole set of advanced settings under the _View Layer_ tab when it is enabled. Making a full guide is a bit much - instead, try looking here - https://renderpool.net/blog/blender-freestyle/#:~:text=Blender's%20Freestyle%20is%20an%20edge,%2Dpainted%2C%20or%20drafted%20looks. - or here - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/index.html

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I found the freestyle configuration, but as you see on the new uploaded picture, it has some odd results like the lines surrounding the circles and a weird line on the top of the pyramid, looks like it takes all the possible borders and highlight them in black

Comment: Yeah, I dunno then. You might have to separate the emission from the rest and render it on a different layer, then add them together in the compositor,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it, what I did was a difference between the output image and the glow, with that result I applied the effect that made the lines.
On the other hand I treated the glow to make it with an alpha background, that alpha was converted and mixed (lightnen applying alpha) with the image that has the lines effect

[image: solution]